# executeEdits resets my edit operation range

Tags: javascript, reactjs, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I'm attempting to do some basic playback of events in Monaco Editor, however, whenever I pass an edit to `executeEdits`, it always resets the `range` of my edit to `{ startLineNumber: 1, startColumn: 1, endLineNumber: 1, endColumn: 1 }` (this is what I get if I `console.log` the message *after* calling `executeEdits`). Effectively, any text I try to insert or replace always ends up at the beginning of the first line and effectively types text in reverse.

[image: typing in reverse]

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor'

import { PlayerContext } from './player-context'

const defaultOptions = {
  minimap: {
    enabled: false
  }
}

export default class MonacoEditor extends React.Component {
  static contextType = PlayerContext

  handleMessage = message => {
    this._editor.executeEdits('', [
      { ...message, forceMoveMarkers: true }
    ])
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { path, value, language, ...options } = this.props
    const model = monaco.editor.createModel(value, language, path)
    this._editor = monaco.editor.create(this._node, {
      ...defaultOptions,
      ...options
    })
    this._editor.setModel(model)
    this.context.addMessageHandler('didChange', this.handleMessage)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._editor && this._editor.dispose()
    this.context.removeMessageHandler('didChange', this.handleMessage)
  }

  render() {
    return <div style={{ height: 500 }} ref={c => (this._node = c)} />
  }
}
```

I am using react to render the Monaco Editor as shown above. A context provides an object that basically allows me to subscribe to playback events, the `message` object passed to `handleMessage` is in the shape of [IIdentifiedSingleEditOperation](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.iidentifiedsingleeditoperation.html)

```
{
  range: {
    startLineNumber: 0, 
    startColumn: 47, 
    endLineNumber: 0, 
    endColumn: 47
  },
  text: '!'
}
```

Why does Monaco reset my edit operation range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation on [`IIdentifiedSingleEditOperation`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.iidentifiedsingleeditoperation.html) says at the `range` property:

> The range to replace. This can be empty to emulate a simple insert.

So you should be able to just pass an empty object and the edit operation will be appended.

However, the [documentation on the `Range` class](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/classes/monaco.range.html) states that line numbers and columns start at 1, not 0. This and the fact that the given range should describe the portion of text which should be **replaced**, not the position where the operation should be appended, causes Monaco to replace the (invalid) range.